# How to find programs that are appropriate to open a file?

Tags: command-line, files

Is there any **command line command** or **any program**  which tells you or suggests you which programs you have installed on your system in order to run your passed file.

For example when I write `command file`, which *command*  is that command which you suggest to me  and file is my file. For example my file is a music file and the result will suggest you have  VLC to run your file.

Or imagine you type `command hello.txt` and the result are **geany** and **vi** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three such programs that identify the file type and run or give a list of suggestions:

- `mimeopen`
- `xdg-open`
- `see`

All of these can be run on the command line.  Their behavior can be modified by various options.  For example:

```
mimeopen -a filename
```

With the `-a` option, `mimeopen` will show a text menu of available programs and prompt you to choose one.  Running `mimeopen -a` on a mp3 file, for example, might produce:

```
$ mimeopen -a somemusic.mp3 
Please choose an application

        1) VLC media player  (vlc)
        2) Enqueue in SMPlayer  (smplayer_enqueue)
        3) GNOME MPlayer  (gnome-mplayer)
        4) SMPlayer  (smplayer)
        5) Audacious  (audacious)

use application #
```

The last line above is a prompt.  If you enter 1,2,3,4 or 5, the associated program will start.  Enter anything else and `mimeopen` will terminate.

In contrast:

```
mimeopen -n filename
```

The above will not ask.  It will just run the default program on `filename`.  To choose/set the default for a file, run:

```
mimeopen -d filename
```

Comment: OP need to know which programs can open a file in terminal , not to open them